# Why use default access for methods in a generic DAO interface?

Tags: java, default, dao, access-modifiers, generic-interface

I found this code for a generic DAO interface while browsing around:

```
public interface GenericDAO<T, ID extends Serializable> {

    Class<T> getEntityClass();

    T findById(final ID id);

    List<T> findAll();
    List<T> findByExample(final T exampleInstance);

    List<T> findByNamedQuery(
        final String queryName,
        Object... params
    );

    List<T> findByNamedQueryAndNamedParams(
        final String queryName,
        final Map<String, ?extends Object> params
    );

    int countAll();

    int countByExample(final T exampleInstance);

    T save(final T entity);

    boolean delete(final T entity);
}
```

Is there any reason in particular for leaving methods with the default access modifier (class/package: yes, subclass/world: no)?

P.S: An added question. Are IDs usually found in implementations which don't depend on a RDBMS (XML, flat file...) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Methods of an interface are implicitely public. Using the public modifier is thus redundant and unnecessary.

[Checkstyle even has a rule](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_modifier.html#RedundantModifier) to check that public is not used in interface methods.

Comment: +1, spot on. To add to it, interface methods are implicitly `public` whereas fields are `public` `static` `final`

Comment: You're right. I'd completely forgotten about this fact. @adarshr: I have yet to encounter fields in an interface. The following topic states that they act as constants: http://www.coderanch.com/t/408233/java/java/Instance-variables-interface

Comment: In passing, any opinions on the question about having an ID?

Comment: Regardless of the technique used to store your persistent objects, you have to be able to identify them uniquely. So I would say yes. BTW, the id attribute in XML has a special meaning: it uniquely identifies an element in the document.